# Async functions return "missing ) after argument list" when type is not module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm kind of new to JavaScript, so please forgive me if I'm overlooking something obvious.

I'm trying to read data from a file in my program and then assign it to a variable.

It works fine as long as I use ECMAScript modules and in my package.json type is set equal to module:

```js
import {promises as fs} from 'fs';

const getDataFromFile = async () => {
    const result = await fs.readFile('input.txt', {encoding:'utf-8'});
    return result
}
console.log(await getDataFromFile())
```

When I use the CommonJS module system and require() syntax, I'm receiving a SyntaxError:

console.log(await getDataFromFile())
^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```js
const {fs: promises} = require('fs');

const getDataFromFile = async () => {
    const result = await fs.readFile('input.txt', {encoding:'utf-8'});
    return result
}
console.log(await getDataFromFile())
```

I tried the same with an async function that uses node pg to get data from a database and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: `await` can only be used at the top level of an ES module. In a CommonJS module, the `await` can only be in an `async` function.

Comment: Use strict mode and you should get a better error message

Comment: Thanks for the answers! So my other question is then how to assign a value returned from an async function to a variable in a CommonJS module?

Comment: @M4rs3l You don't. You use `then()`. The best you can get in the module scope is a variable holding a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Outside async function, use classic then promise.

```
getDataFromFile().then(result => { console.log(result) });
```